# Get a value from multidimensional, with variable number of dimensions, dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional dictionary. List of dimensions is given as a variable. How do I use all the dimensions in that list and access the value stored at the end.

```
def get_value(dict, dimensions):
    """
    dict is the multidimensional dict
    dimensions is a list of strings which specify all the dimensions
    """
```

How do I write the below command in a pythonic way

```
    dict[dimensions[0]][dimensions[1]][dimensions[2]]......[dimensions[len(dimensions)-1]]
```

Comment: First one warning - using Python reserved words for variable names is dangerous, in your case you use `dict`. I usually use `dct` for this purpose.

Comment: `while (dimensions): dict = dict[dimensions.pop(0)]` <-- 3 caveats: 1. Don't name it `dict`, 2. It's more efficient if `dimensions` comes in reversed order (so you can use `pop` not `pop(0)`), 3. don't use your only copy of `dict` since this will change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not too difficult, suppose you wrote this in a slightly different way:

```
dict = dict[dimensions[0]]
dict = dict[dimensions[1]]
dict = dict[dimensions[2]]
......
dict = dict[dimensions[len(dimensions)-1]]
```

we see a pattern.  Another thing to notice is that we're just iterating through dimensions, we can do this as:

```
for d in dimensions:
    dict = dict[d]
```

so, in fact, we can do:

```
def get_value(mapping, keys):
    for key in keys:
        mapping = mapping[key]
    return mapping
```

Interestingly, python has a shortcut for this pattern, repeatedly applying an operation to an initial element, one for each element of another sequence, `reduce()`

```
def get_value(mapping, keys):
    return reduce(dict.get, keys, mapping)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and steps one might/should take to arrive at that.